# Unique constraint across foreign keys in Sequelize model

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a simple Sequelize model that is associated with other models.

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Votes = sequelize.define('Votes', {
    isUpVote: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        Votes.belongsTo(models.Track);
        Votes.belongsTo(models.User);
      }
    }
  });

  return Votes;
}
```

Sequelize will generate a table with an `id`, `TrackId`, `UserId` and `isUpVote`.

I want to set a `UNIQUE` constraint across `TrackId` and `UserId` (i.e. a composite index ensuring that there is only one vote record for a given track and user).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use the unique constraint and give it a string rather than a bool. Then another other fields with the same string will become part of the same composite index.

i.e.:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
   var Votes = sequelize.define('Votes', {
      isUpVote: {
          type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
          unique: 'myCompositeIndexName'
      },
      TrackId: {
          type: DataType.INTEGER
          unique: 'myCompositeIndexName',
      },
      UserId: {
          type: DataType.INTEGER
          unique: 'myCompositeIndexName',
      }
   }, {
       classMethods: {
           associate: function (models) {
               Votes.belongsTo(models.Track);
               Votes.belongsTo(models.User);
           }
       }
    });

    return Votes;
}
```

(^Not tested, just off the top of my head!)

The problem with this is that this will only occur during the creation of a table. If you table already exists, you can achieve this by using the migrations feature of sequelize-cli.

I really hope this helps else at least points you in the right direction. If you are still stuck, I recommend you go to the IRC channel for sequelize as it seems to be pretty active.

Comment: How would you define a composite unique index on a join table in an n:many situation?

Comment: When I try, it throws: `SequelizeDatabaseError: foreign key constraint "event_related_info_<foreign name>_fkey" cannot be implemented`

Comment: what if I want TrackId to appear in 2 different composite keys? example (TrackId, UserId), (TrackId, isUpVote)

Answer (score 2):

What ended up working for me was adding it under [indexes](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/indexes.html), e.g.:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Votes = sequelize.define('Votes', {
    isUpVote: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
    indexes: [
      {
        unique: true,
        fields: ['TrackId', 'UserId'],
      },
    ],
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        Votes.belongsTo(models.Track);
        Votes.belongsTo(models.User);
      },
    },
  });

  return Votes;
}
```