# Sequelize composite unique constraint

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Defining model:

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
   return sequelize.define('Item', {
       minor: DataTypes.INTEGER,
       major: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   });
}
```

Can I define the pair minor and major as a composite UNIQUE constraint?

Answer (score 46):

Recently, in V4, Sequelize has a method [`addConstraint`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint) on the query interface:

```
queryInterface.addConstraint('Items', {
  fields: ['minor', 'major'],
  type: 'unique',
  name: 'custom_unique_constraint_name'
});
```

Comment: This is now out of date -- pass in the array of fields as `fields` within the `options` object.

Comment: Just in case anyone is confused by the comment above, it is no longer out of date thanks to an update made by @the-red-pea

Comment: for teardown    `await queryInterface.removeConstraint('Items', 'custom_unique_constraint_name')`

Answer (score 27):

```
queryInterface.createTable(
  'Item', 
  {
    minor: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    major: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    }
  }, 
  {
    uniqueKeys: {
      Items_unique: {
        fields: ['minor', 'major']
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: @MuhammadUmer this one is the easiest way to add unique composite key, it's strange that it's not popular and someone even down voted this answer

Comment: It's weird that this worked for me in my migration file but the official doc even said to use it as 
`major: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'compositeIndex'},
minor: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'compositeIndex'}`

Comment: this answer worked for me, but how can I provide more than one pair of unique fields

Comment: `{ uniqueKeys: { Items_unique: { fields: ['minor', 'major'] }, Second_unique_pair: { fields: ['some_field_1', 'some_field_2']  } }` @Hasan

Comment: This question is not asking for a unique composite index, but a generic unique composite constraint. Correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/64712973/3158815

Answer (score 22):

Here is the simple answer:

```
major: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'compositeIndex'},
minor: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'compositeIndex'}
```

source: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#column-options

> ```
> // Creating two objects with the same value will throw an error. > The unique property can be either a
> // boolean, or a string. If you provide the same string for > multiple columns, they will form a
> // composite unique key.
> uniqueOne: { type: DataTypes.STRING,  unique: 'compositeIndex' },
> uniqueTwo: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'compositeIndex' },
> ```

You can also create a unique constraint through belongsToMany associations if it's a join table:

```
Major = sequelize.define('major', {})
Minor = sequelize.define('minor', {})

Major.belongsToMany(Project)
Minor.belongsToMany(User)
```

Source: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/associations/

In my case, I wanted to find a way to enforce this with my migration. I did this by appending a raw sql query at the end of my up function:

```
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
return queryInterface.createTable('Item', {
  major: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
  minor: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
})
.then(function() {
  return queryInterface.sequelize.query(
    'ALTER TABLE `Item` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`major`, `minor`)'
  );
});
```

Related Questions:

[Sequelize, foreign keys as composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883437/sequelize-foreign-keys-as-composite-primary-key/36884615#36884615)

[Unique constraint across foreign keys in Sequelize model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551941/unique-constraint-across-foreign-keys-in-sequelize-model)

Comment: there it turned out there are multiple options. This question is difficult to answer cause it strongly depends on the used db and te sequalize version. This thing doesn't feel stable better to avoid it.

Comment: Actually, it's adding 2 composite unique constraints, one on property_manager_uid and tenand_uid, the other on user_uid and door_uid. Is there not a way to tell sequelize not to add any primary keys or constraints? Why is sequelize presuming to know what I want in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by using [`addConstraint(...)`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-addConstraint):

```js
await queryInterface.addConstraint('Item', {
  fields: ['minor', 'major'],
  type: 'unique',
  name: 'unique_constraint_name'
});
```

This is as of at least v6+.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
      return queryInterface.createTable('item',
        {
          minor: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          },
          major: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          }
        }, { transaction: t }
      ).then(() => {
        return queryInterface.addConstraint(
          'item',
          ['minor', 'major'],
          {
            type: 'unique',
            name: 'Items_unique'
          },
          {
            transaction: t
          }
        );
      });
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('item');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For ES6 Migrations

```
const item = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('Items', {
    minor: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    major: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }).then(() => queryInterface.addConstraint('Items', ['minor', 'major'], {
    type: 'unique',
    name: 'composite_key_name'
  })),
  down: queryInterface => queryInterface.dropTable('Items')
};

export default item;
```

Answer (score 0):

**`sequelize.define('', {}, {indexes: [ { unique: true`**

Another way besides [Jake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495485/895245):

```
const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
    minor: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    major: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    indexes: [
      {
        fields: ['minor', 'major'],
        unique: true,
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

which automatically creates the name based on the fields, SQLite query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Items` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `minor` INTEGER,
  `major` INTEGER,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL
);
PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`Items`)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `items_minor_major` ON `Items` (`minor`, `major`)
```

Documented at: [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-init](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-init)

> `options.indexes[].unique`:
> Should the index by unique? Can also be triggered by setting type to UNIQUE

The approach on Jake's answer:

```
const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
  minor: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'asdf' },
  major: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, unique: 'asdf' },
})
```

produces instead an anonymous `UNIQUE` constraint (which automatically implies an index I believe), so both are very similar except for the name:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Items` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `minor` INTEGER,
  `major` INTEGER,
  `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (`minor`, `major`)
);
PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`Items`)
PRAGMA INDEX_INFO(`sqlite_autoindex_Items_1`)
```

PostgreSQL queries are analogous.

Full runnable example:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
let sequelize
if (process.argv[2] === 'p') {
  sequelize = new Sequelize('tmp', undefined, undefined, {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '/var/run/postgresql',
  })
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: 'tmp.sqlite'
  })
}
;(async () => {
const Item = sequelize.define('Item', {
    minor: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    major: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    indexes: [
      {
        fields: ['minor', 'major'],
        unique: true,
      }
    ]
  }
)
await Item.sync({ force: true })
await Item.create({ minor: 1, major: 1 })
await Item.create({ minor: 1, major: 2 })
let threw = false
try {
  await Item.create({ minor: 1, major: 2 })
} catch (e) {
  threw = true
}
assert(threw)
})().finally(() => { return sequelize.close() })
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "8.5.1",
    "pg-hstore": "2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "6.14.0",
    "sql-formatter": "4.0.2",
    "sqlite3": "5.0.2"
  }
}
```

tested on PostgreSQL 13.5.

Comment: How can one go about creating a composite index with a foreign key. I'd like to make a constraint that `productUrl` needs to be unique for each `userId` (foreign key) in `products` table.

Association
`Product.belongsTo(User)`

Comment: @Tajs it should just work if use use `productUrl` and `userId`, `userId` can be used even though it is automatically defined by Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to mention this for posterity's sake. I have a Postgres database and was looking at how to add constraints. We ended up using indexes for our constraints, on the model it looks like this

```
        sequelize,
        tableName: "table_name",
        timestamps: false,
        paranoid: true,
        indexes: [
            {
                name: "PRIMARY",
                unique: true,
                using: "BTREE",
                fields: [{ name: "field_id" }],
            },
            {
                name: "UniqueConstraint_1",
                unique: true,
                using: "BTREE",
                fields: [
                    { name: "user_id" },
                    { name: "player_id" },
                    { name: "game_id" },
                ],
            },
```

That will allow you to have a unique "constraint" on the database. It will show up in indexes instead of constraints however.