# Sequelize trying to enter data into an unknown column [Postgres]

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

Here's my query that's failing:

```
Models.OrdersProducts.create({
  orderId: 1,
  productId: 1,
});
```

with the error:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "OrdersProducts" ("orderId","productId","createdAt","updatedAt","OrderId") VALUES (1,1,'2018-02-25 12:51:00.110 +00:00
','2018-02-25 12:51:00.110 +00:00',NULL) RETURNING *;
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column "OrderId" of relation "OrdersProducts" does not exist
    at Query.formatError (/Users/aakashverma/Documents/sequelize-join-table/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:363:16)
```

where my table doesn't have the column `OrderId`(with capital O) and only `orderId`

**NOTE**: My `Orders` and `Products` tables do have an entry with `id` 1, that's not the problem.

---

This is my migration for `OrdersProducts`:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('OrdersProducts', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    orderId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'Orders',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    productId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'Products',
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE,
    },
  }),
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.dropTable('OrdersProducts'),
};
```

and here are the models file:

*models/OrdersProducts.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const OrdersProducts = sequelize.define('OrdersProducts', {
    orderId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    productId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});
  return OrdersProducts;
};
```

*models/Orders.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Orders = sequelize.define('Orders', {
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});
  Orders.associate = function (models) {
    Orders.belongsTo(models.Users);
    Orders.belongsToMany(models.Products, { through: 'OrdersProducts', as: 'product' });
  };
  return Orders;
};
```

*models/Products.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Products = sequelize.define('Products', {
    name: DataTypes.TEXT,
  }, {});
  Products.associate = function (models) {
    Products.belongsToMany(models.Orders, { through: 'OrdersProducts', as: 'order' });
  };
  return Products;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird.

N.B. I am using 1 as the id in queries because this is the autoincrement `id` key value as I only add one entry in any table whatsoever.

Looking at my `Orders` model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Orders = sequelize.define('Orders', {
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});
  Orders.associate = function (models) {
    Orders.belongsTo(models.Users);
```

> Orders.belongsToMany(models.Products, { through: 'OrdersProducts', as: 'product' });

```
  };
 return Orders;
};
```

and my`Products` model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Products = sequelize.define('Products', {
    name: DataTypes.TEXT,
  }, {});
  Products.associate = function (models) {
```

> Products.belongsToMany(models.Orders, { through: 'OrdersProducts', as: 'order' });

```
   };
  return Products;
};
```

*These two seem to create attributes of their own for my* `OrdersProducts` table as **`OrderId`** and **`ProductId`** (with first letter capital; **don't know why and how they are generating the name**) and therefore, I was getting that **`OrderId`** thingy.

If I remove the `belongToMany` association from the `Orders` model, I stared to get the same error with `ProductId` column instead.

Finally, I found [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883437/sequelize-foreign-keys-as-composite-primary-key) which told me, in a way, to use the columns provided by the associations and drop the corresponding in the `OrdersProducts` column.

Now my query, *which works fine BTW*, looks like:

```
const Models = require('./models');

// Models.Users.create({
//   name: 'Aakash',
// });

// Models.Orders.create({
//   userId: 1,
// });

// Models.Products.create({
//   name: 'lash',
// });

Models.OrdersProducts.create({
  OrderId: 1,
  ProductId: 1,
});
```

and model looks like (pay attention to the capital letters, again):

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const OrdersProducts = sequelize.define('OrdersProducts', {
    OrderId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ProductId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});
  return OrdersProducts;
};
```

### The mystery about the automatic column naming still exists.

---

P.S. This is the weirdest part.

Now I have a table `Users` as you'd have been able to see from my code above. Pay attention to how the `belongsTo` plays in the models.

*models/users.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Users.associate = function (models) {
    Users.hasMany(models.Orders);
  };
  return Users;
};
```

*models/orders.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Orders = sequelize.define('Orders', {
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});
  Orders.associate = function (models) {
    Orders.belongsTo(models.Users);
    Orders.belongsToMany(models.Products, { through: 'OrdersProducts', as: 'product' });
  };
  return Orders;
};
```

The query below *still works* and adds an entry to `Orders` (look at how it doesn't require me to remove `userId` column from the `Orders` table nor does it come up with its own `UserId` -_-):

```
Models.Users.create({
  name: 'Aakash',
});
Models.Orders.create({
  userId: 1,
});
```

*models/users.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
  Users.associate = function (models) {
    Users.hasMany(models.Orders);
  };
  return Users;
};
```

*models/orders.js*

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Orders = sequelize.define('Orders', {
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {});
  Orders.associate = function (models) {
    Orders.belongsTo(models.Users);
    Orders.belongsToMany(models.Products, { through: 'OrdersProducts', as: 'product' });
  };
  return Orders;
};
```

Comment: similar issue, any updates on this ?