# How do I add a unique nonclustered constraint using Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't find it anywhere in the documentation of Sequelize.

```sql
create table User (
    id int unique,
    lastname varchar(255),
    firstname varchar(255),
    Unique (lastname),
    Constraint UN_people2 unique (firstname,lastname)
)
```

Main Problem

```sql
Constraint UN_people2 unique (firstname,lastname)
```

How to do this in Sequelize?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664853/sequelize-composite-unique-constraint

Answer (score 0):

if you define your model in a different file, you can use the `options` object to specify `indexes` array:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      firstname: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
      lastname: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    },
    {
      indexes: [
        {
          name: 'user_unique_names',
          unique: true,
          type: 'NONCLUSTERED',
          fields: [
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  );

  return User;
};
```